# How to insert rows into a table using a select statment along with user input value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to add one custom value to colum while a insert with select statment is running ?

```
INSERT INTO CORPDATA.EMPTIME
     (EMPNUMBER, PROJNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
  SELECT EMPNO, PROJNO, EMSTDATE, EMENDATE
    FROM CORPDATA.EMPPROJACT
```

I know the above will copy the records from the `EMPPROJACT to EMPTIME.`  But I am trying to insert a new value to one of column in `CORPDATA.EMPTIME` along with copying . Say I have a colum named `PROJNAME` in `CORPDATA.EMPTIME` which is custom value  called `'Default Project Name'`. I need to insert the same while running the above query

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO corpdata.emptime 
            (empnumber, 
             projnumber, 
             startdate, 
             enddate, 
             projname) 
SELECT empno, 
       projno, 
       emstdate, 
       emendate, 
       'Project Name' AS PROJNAME 
FROM   corpdata.empprojact
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, Try this:

```
INSERT INTO CORPDATA.EMPTIME
 (EMPNUMBER, PROJNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE,PROJNAME)
 SELECT EMPNO, PROJNO, EMSTDATE, EMENDATE,'Default Project Name'
 FROM CORPDATA.EMPPROJACT
```

Comment: Oops u were faster than me! ;)

Comment: @Ean I guess AbdulManaf was 1 second faster than me.

Comment: Yeah but your answer was exactly same as mine letter by letter :D